# Count the number of specific records retrieved from the database and using the count in the <td> as rowspan

Tags: php, html-table

```
<?php
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->district == 'Arghakhachi') {
        $count += count($value->district);
        ?>
        <tr>
            <!-- <td><?= $key + 1 ?></td> -->
            <td rowspan="<?php ($key == 0) ? echo $count : '' ?>"><?= $value->district ?></td>
            <td><?= $value->fiscal_Year ?></td>
            <td><?= $value->animal_distributed_total ?></td>
            <td><?= $value->total_animal_ai_ni_total ?></td>
            <td><?= $value->ni_conceived_animal_total ?></td>
            <td><?= $value->ni_produced_animal_total_female_male ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php }} ?>
```

I want the first td to merge the rows based on the total count value only if the district name is Argakhanchi. I am getting all the output as desired leaving the rowspan.
Since the td is inside the loop, the code gives me increment of count on every loop but I want that as a total count at once.

Can anybody help me with this please?

The value stored in $data.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fiscal_Year] => 2071/72
        [district] => Arghakhachi
        [animal_distributed_total] => 0
        [ai_animal_total] => 232
        [ai_convicted_animal_total_female_male] => 59
        [ni_animal_total] => 61
        [total_animal_ai_ni_female_male] => 0
        [total_animal_ai_ni_total] => 0
        [ni_conceived_animal_total] => 0
        [ni_produced_animal_total_female_male] => 0
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fiscal_Year] => 2072/73
        [district] => Arghakhachi
        [animal_distributed_total] => 12
        [ai_animal_total] => 785
        [ai_convicted_animal_total_female_male] => 198
        [ni_animal_total] => 217
        [total_animal_ai_ni_female_male] => 0
        [total_animal_ai_ni_total] => 0
        [ni_conceived_animal_total] => 0
        [ni_produced_animal_total_female_male] => 0
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fiscal_Year] => 2072/73
        [district] => Gulmi
        [animal_distributed_total] => 2
        [ai_animal_total] => 831
        [ai_convicted_animal_total_female_male] => 129
        [ni_animal_total] => 285
        [total_animal_ai_ni_female_male] => 0
        [total_animal_ai_ni_total] => 0
        [ni_conceived_animal_total] => 0
        [ni_produced_animal_total_female_male] => 0
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fiscal_Year] => 2072/73
        [district] => Pyuthan
        [animal_distributed_total] => 0
        [ai_animal_total] => 123
        [ai_convicted_animal_total_female_male] => 0
        [ni_animal_total] => 0
        [total_animal_ai_ni_female_male] => 0
        [total_animal_ai_ni_total] => 0
        [ni_conceived_animal_total] => 0
        [ni_produced_animal_total_female_male] => 0
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fiscal_Year] => 2072/73
        [district] => Rolpa
        [animal_distributed_total] => 2
        [ai_animal_total] => 119
        [ai_convicted_animal_total_female_male] => 21
        [ni_animal_total] => 29
        [total_animal_ai_ni_female_male] => 0
        [total_animal_ai_ni_total] => 0
        [ni_conceived_animal_total] => 0
        [ni_produced_animal_total_female_male] => 0
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fiscal_Year] => 2073/74
        [district] => Arghakhachi
        [animal_distributed_total] => 8
        [ai_animal_total] => 869
        [ai_convicted_animal_total_female_male] => 251
        [ni_animal_total] => 278
        [total_animal_ai_ni_female_male] => 0
        [total_animal_ai_ni_total] => 0
        [ni_conceived_animal_total] => 0
        [ni_produced_animal_total_female_male] => 0
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [fiscal_Year] => 2073/74
        [district] => Gulmi
        [animal_distributed_total] => 8
        [ai_animal_total] => 803
        [ai_convicted_animal_total_female_male] => 148
        [ni_animal_total] => 213
        [total_animal_ai_ni_female_male] => 0
        [total_animal_ai_ni_total] => 0
        [ni_conceived_animal_total] => 0
        [ni_produced_animal_total_female_male] => 0
    )
```

SQL Code :

```
select 
          bin.fiscal_Year,bin.district
          ,sum(bin.animal_distributed_total)  animal_distributed_total
          ,sum(bin.ai_animal_total)  ai_animal_total
          ,(sum(bin.ai_convicted_animal_total_male) + sum(ai_convicted_animal_total_female) )  ai_convicted_animal_total_female_male
          ,sum(bin.ni_animal_total) ni_animal_total
          ,(sum(bin.total_animal_ai_ni_male) + sum(bin.total_animal_ai_ni_female) ) total_animal_ai_ni_female_male
          ,sum(bin.total_animal_ai_ni_total)  total_animal_ai_ni_total
          ,sum(bin.ni_conceived_animal_total) ni_conceived_animal_total
          ,(sum(bin.ni_produced_animal_total_male)+sum(bin.ni_produced_animal_total_female) ) ni_produced_animal_total_female_male
          from breed_improvement_new bin 
          group by bin.fiscal_Year,bin.district
```

Comment: can you show the data stored in `$data`

Comment: if `$count` can't be computed before the loop, you will have to iterate twice over `$data` so that the rowspan number can be known before writing the `TD`.

Comment: I have updated  the question with the value of $data being fetched.

Comment: _“only if the district name is Argakhanchi”_ - so you only want to do this for this one district? Even if one of the others occurred multiple times, for those you’d still want one independent table row for each occurrence? Anyway, if you want to show the data for that Argakhanchi district “grouped”, then you should start by sorting your data by district first of all (because looping over those records in just any arbitrary order, would not make much sense to begin with, given your requirement.)

Comment: Use `array_column` to extract the values of the `district` property, then `array_count_values` to count how often they occur. Pick the `Argakhanchi` entry from the resulting array, that’s your count.

Comment: to make it more clear I would like to do the operation for every single district. But if the issue can be resolved for one district, it would be easier for me to do that for others too.

Comment: misorude sir, I have also added the sql above.

Comment: Well I already suggested how to do it for one district.

Answer (score 0):

Before you get into the printing loop you should find how many rows for this district you have.

```
<?php
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->district == 'Arghakhachi') {
        $district[$value->district]=$value;
    }
}
```

And keep in mind that you should omit the first td for the next rows.

```
foreach ($district['Arghakhachi'] as $key=> $value) {
    if($key==0){
    ?>
    <tr>     
        <td rowspan="<?=count($district['Arghakhachi'])?>"><?= $value->district ?></td>
        <td><?= $value->fiscal_Year ?></td>
        <td><?= $value->animal_distributed_total ?></td>
        <td><?= $value->total_animal_ai_ni_total ?></td>
        <td><?= $value->ni_conceived_animal_total ?></td>
        <td><?= $value->ni_produced_animal_total_female_male ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }else{ ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?= $value->fiscal_Year ?></td>
        <td><?= $value->animal_distributed_total ?></td>
        <td><?= $value->total_animal_ai_ni_total ?></td>
        <td><?= $value->ni_conceived_animal_total ?></td>
        <td><?= $value->ni_produced_animal_total_female_male ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

I did not test this. but I am sure that will work maybe with some small modifications.